# How to assign a shortcut key to Control-Command-B?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

I notice that I cannot assign the key combination `Control-Command-B` as a shortcut key for any application like Emacs, [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/). When setting this key combination into the Preferences of Spectacle, what is recorded is just `Control-Command`, instead of `Control-Command-B`.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this key combination?

The reason that I need to use this key is to assign it to the function `backward-sexp` in Emacs that move backward an s-expression. I'm using macOS Catalina in my Macbook Pro 15'' 2019.

Thank you in advance for taking a look at my question.

---

**Update 1:** I forgot to mention that I use Karabiner-Elements to switch Function and Control. So, the physical keys that I want to ask is actually `Function-Command-B`.

Comment: Is your B key working?

Comment: Yes, `B`, `Control-B`, `Command-B` all work. But not `Control-Command-B`

Comment: I can confirm that it works for me as a user shortcut for third-party apps, assigned in System Preferences. This on Mojave 10.15.6. 
Have you tested the problem in a new user account? That will indicate whether it's just some other user preference getting in the way, or if it's at the system/hardware level.

Comment: @benwiggy Oh, I forgot to mention that I use Karabiner-Elements to switch `Function` and `Control`. So, the physical keys that I want to ask is `Function-Command-B`.